# MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemId) returns null in Robolectric

Tags: robolectric, android-testing

We know that Robolectric just keeps silent by giving null, 0 values for invocation that is not implemented. And it seems that it doesn't handle method call `MenuItemCompat.getActionView()` well. See the following snippet which is failed to execute with Robolectric.

```java
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
```

On this snippet, Robolectric is failed to retrieve SearchView object, making the searchView variable to be null. Perhaps Robolectric misses some shadow implementations here?

After debugging, I found that prior to calling `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionView()`, the `MenuItemImpl` instance already doesn't have `mActionView` (mActionView = null), where in non-compat one does have.

The more I debug, the more I understand the problem. The problem is this line of `ShadowMenuInflater.addActionViewToItem()`

```java
String actionViewClassName = 
    attributes.getAttributeValue(ANDROID_NS, "actionViewClass");
```

It only cares about ANDROID_NS not APP_NS as AppCompat use APP_NS instead.

I think it'd be better if Robolectric gives me exceptions to let me know which shadows to implement.

I have also filed this case to [GitHub](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1166)

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry. I gave up using robolectric. For a moment, I do eagle eye testing :) So sad...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I actually managed to extend the shadow class and overwrite the method like so:

@Implements(SupportMenuInflater.class)
public class ShadowSupportMenuInflater extends ShadowMenuInflater {

But then I could not figure out, which actionViewClassName needed to be supplied.

Comment: @PhilippE. Agreed! Although Robolectric implementators suggest adding new shadow classes to the API. But, I din't find it easy to do that as I am new to Android.

Comment: This is fixed in Robolectric 3.0-rc3.